# Selecting matching rows in table joined by non-unique key without reusing rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables which I want to join on column with non-unique values, but in a way that results with only one row per matching pair and no duplicated lines on any side. Each of those tables also contains column with table-unique data **(that does not match)**.

i.e.:

Table A:

| key | unique-data |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |

Table B:

| key | unique-data |
| --- | --- |
| A | **3** |
| A | **4** |

I want to get **either** of those:

| A.key | B.key | a.unique-data | b.unique-data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | 1 | **3** |
| A | A | 2 | **4** |

| A.key | B.key | a.unique-data | b.unique-data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | 2 | **4** |
| A | A | 1 | **3** |

But **not** the whole matrix

| A.key | B.key | a.unique-data | b.unique-data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | 2 | **3** |
| A | A | 1 | **4** |
| A | A | 1 | **3** |
| A | A | 2 | **4** |

The issue is that those rows have to be matched by this non-unique values and there can be a lot of them (100'000s), so a join by key is impossible slow.

Answer (score 0):

Though your key field is not unique but you have unique-data field having unique value. So join both tables on both the columns as below:

```
select a.[key] [a.key],b.[key] [b.key],a.[unique-data] [a.unique-data],b.[unique-data] [b.unique-data]
from
(select [key],[unique-data] ,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by [key] order by [unique-data])  rn from tablea)a
inner join
(select [key],[unique-data] ,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by [key] order by [unique-data])  rn from tableb)b
on a.rn=b.rn
```

**Output:**

```
|a.key|b.key|a.unique-data|b.unique-data|
|A    |A    |1            |3            |
|A    |A    |2            |4            |
```

If number of rows for a key in each table doesn't match and you want to have all rows in result then you can use full join:

```
select a.[key] [a.key],b.[key] [b.key],a.[unique-data] [a.unique-data],b.[unique-data] [b.unique-data]
from
(select [key],[unique-data] ,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by [key] order by [unique-data])  rn from tablea)a
 full join
(select [key],[unique-data] ,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by [key] order by [unique-data])  rn from tableb)b
on a.rn=b.rn
```

**Output:**

```
|a.key|b.key|a.unique-data|b.unique-data|
|A    |A    |1            |3            |
|A    |A    |2            |4            |
|NULL |A    |NULL         |4            |
```

Comment: I have updated the example, unfortunately the unique-data does not match, my example was oversimplified. Furthermore, there can be more rows with the same key on each side of the table.

Comment: If there is always same number of row for each key in each table my new answer will satisfy your need.

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

You can just `join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.key = t2.key and
        t1.unique_data = t2.unique_data;
```

(Note:  `key` is a SQL keyword so it is not a good choice for a column name.)

For performance you want an index on `(key, unique_data)`.  This will probably work on either table, but you can put the index on both.

I should point out that if `unique_data` is really unique, you might be able to do the `join` on a single column:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.unique_data = t2.unique_data;
```

It is not clear from your question if this is a viable approach.

Comment: I have updated the example, unfortunately the unique-data does not match, my example was oversimplified. Furthermore, there can be more rows with the same key on each side of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Find pairs, augment a pair with other data from the original tables if any

```
select t1.key, t1.unique-data, t2.unique-data, A.other-data, B.other-data
from (
   select key, max(unique-data) unique-data
   from A
   group by key ) t1
join (
   select key, max(unique-data) unique-data
   from B
   group by key ) t2 on t1.key = t2.key
join A on t1.unique-data = A.unique-data
join B on t2.unique-data = B.unique-data
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values of the column `unique_data` in `TableA` match the values of `unique_data` in `TableB` then all you have to do use this match also when you join the tables:

```
SELECT a.key a_key, b.key b_key, a.unique_data a_unique_data, b.unique_data b_unique_data
FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b
ON (b.key, b.unique_data) = (a.key, a.unique_data)
```

But if they don't match, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to create row numbers for each `key` and use them instead of `unique_data`:

```
SELECT a.key a_key, b.key b_key, a.unique_data a_unique_data, b.unique_data b_unique_data
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY key ORDER BY unique_data) rn FROM TableA) a
INNER JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY key ORDER BY unique_data) rn FROM TableB) b
ON (b.key, b.rn) = (a.key, a.rn)
```

Comment: I have updated the example, unfortunately the unique-data does not match, my example was oversimplified. Furthermore, there can be more rows with the same key on each side of the table.

Comment: @M.Stefański my 2nd query works for this case. Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=1352c8d07ef06a8e82079da4a7faa59f